# What should be the format of "Date" in text file to be read as Json and then inserted into MongoDB using Python?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, bson

I need to do the following in my code:

- Read data from a text file
- Convert the data into Json
- Upsert the data into MongoDB

Here is an example of how the content of text file is going to look:

```
{
   "S": "someString" <- Type String when inerted in mongodb
   "N": 123          <- Type Int32
   "F": 12.3         <- Type Double
   "D": ?            <- Need to be Type DateTime when inerted in mongodb
}
```

I don't know what I am suppose to have in the place of the "?" so when I use bson.json_util.loads function in python it can properly convert the text file into Json which later can be inserted into mongoDB.

Here is the code that does the load and insert:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = json_util.loads(f.read())
    db[dbName][colName].update({'_id': id}, data, upsert=True,safe=True)
```

I would appreciate it if someone can give an example of how the file should be formatted. (If your example can include even more complex Bson types like type "binary" or "code" that would be nice too :) )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mongo's representation of datetimes is `{"$date": number-of-milliseconds-since-epoch}`. In your example:

```
{
   "S": "someString",
   "N": 123,
   "F": 12.3,
   "D": {"$date": 1352540684243}
}
```

`D` will generate a datetime field when written to mongo.

See [the documentation for mongo json extensions](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Extended+JSON).

You can also easily extend `json_util` to program your own extensions, for example, for ISO-formatted datetimes:

```
import json, dateutil.parser, bson.json_util

a = """{
    "mydate": {"$isodate": "2012-11-01T20:19:55.782Z"}
}"""

def my_hook(dct):
    if '$isodate' in dct:
        return dateutil.parser.parse(dct['$isodate'])
    return bson.json_util.object_hook(dct)

obj = json.loads(a, object_hook=my_hook)
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually read that document and tried it out before I read your answer and it does work, but I was mostly looking for something like $datetime that would take an ISO standard string like this {"$datetime": "2012-11-11Z"} and I am very disappointed by the fact that there is none! looking at a text file that has number-of-milliseconds-since-epochis for a date is not really convenient!

Comment: @IdaN: yes, there's no such thing, but it can be easily added: see the update.

Comment: Wow Thanks:) you are one step ahead of me! I was actually thinking of passing a custom encoder class to `load(fp, cls=None, object_hook=None, parse_float=None, parse_int=None, parse_constant=None, object_pairs_hook=None, **kw)` I was trying to figuer out how I can do that!

Answer (score 0):

JSON doesn't know anything about dates, so it's up to you to decide upon a standard format to serialize to and deserialize from.  It'll be stored as a string in MongoDB, so just make sure you use the same format string when you call strftime and strptime in your Python code.

Comment: Based on this documentation (http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.3/api/bson/json_util.html?highlight=json_util#bson.json_util) I should be able to do encode / decode BSON documents to JSON even when they use special BSON types using json_util, I just haven't figured out how, yet.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.  I think sean has the right idea with the timestamp now that I've taken a look at bsonspec.org.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a timestamp. They are very easy to work with and require no real special handling besides in your actual program code or can easily be left alone as the integer that they are. I have dealt with format strings and there really isn't a nice way to ensure they are the same everywhere, hence why I have moved towards using a timestamp whenever possible.

Comment: That's a good point, sean.  Actually, if you look at the bsonspec.org, the datetime data type they have is just a 64bit int that represents a standard utc timestamp.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I would have adopted the idea of using timestamp if I was starting fresh, but in my case I will be inserting the data in preexisting mongo collection which already has data in it with type "DateTime" and the collection is being used in a C# code mapped to a c# class that expects DateTime! so it is a bit complected and I am stuck with the format!